# Bootstrap fixed table header not hiding form/button glyphicon

Tags: html, css

I have a table with a fixed header, and in one of the columns there are delete buttons within a form:

```
<div class="panel panel-default table-responsive fixedHeader">
  <!-- Table -->
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <!--table headers are here-->
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for row in hoursDb %}
      <tr>
        <!-- all rows are called here, just saving space -->
        <td>
          <form action="" method="post">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="delete" value="{{ row[7] }}">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
            </button>
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I used the following css to get a fixed header:

```
.fixedHeader {
    height:40vh;
    overflow-y:auto;
}

.fixedHeader th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

table  { border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
th, td { padding: 8px 16px; }
th     { background:#eee; }
```

The other row data are hidden by the header when scrolled, but the problem is that when I scroll within the table, the remove glyphicon is still showing and I am able to click on the button which deletes the row.

How would I change it so the table header covers the form/button/glyphicon?

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using Z-index? Share snapshot if possible.